# OpenGL triangles unwanted edge border

Tags: opengl, haskell

I'm trying to render a square with texture.
It's working, except I'm getting a pixelated line on the diagonal edge where two triangles meet each other.

The texture:

[image: Texture used on the squares]

The render result of three squares, each square is made of two triangles:

[image: Render result]

The line only shows up on diagonal lines. Nothing appears on the vertical or horizontal edges.

Code:

```
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL
import qualified Graphics.UI.GLFW          as GLFW
```

Initialization:

```
GL.lineSmooth    $= GL.Enabled
GL.polygonSmooth $= GL.Enabled
GL.blend         $= GL.Enabled -- A
GL.blendFunc     $= (GL.SrcAlpha, GL.OneMinusSrcAlpha)
GL.lineWidth     $= 1.5
```

Loading the texture:

```
GL.texture GL.Texture2D $= GL.Enabled
(texName:_) <- GL.genObjectNames 1
GL.textureBinding GL.Texture2D $= Just texName
GL.textureFilter GL.Texture2D $= ((GL.Nearest, Nothing), GL.Nearest)
_ <- GLFW.loadTexture2D "wall.tga" [GLFW.BuildMipMaps]
```

Rendering the quad:

```
GL.textureBinding GL.Texture2D $= Just texName
GL.renderPrimitive GL.TriangleStrip $ do
    GL.texCoord $ GL.TexCoord2 0 (1::GL.GLfloat)
    GL.vertex $ vertex3 20 0 0
    GL.texCoord $ GL.TexCoord2 0 (0::GL.GLfloat)
    GL.vertex $ vertex3 20 20 0
    GL.texCoord $ GL.TexCoord2 1 (1::GL.GLfloat)
    GL.vertex $ vertex3 0 0 0
    GL.texCoord $ GL.TexCoord2 1 (0::GL.GLfloat)
    GL.vertex $ vertex3 0 20 0
GL.textureBinding GL.Texture2D $= Nothing
```

I've tried rendering `GL.Polygons` and `GL.Quads`: same result.

They go away when I comment the line tagged with `-- A`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with the line `GL.polygonSmooth $= GL.Enabled`. It seems to smooth all edges of the polygon, even if there is another edge over it.

Removing this line works, even maintaining the `GL.blend $= GL.Enabled`.

The [Common Mistakes page at OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#glEnable.28GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH.29) says:

> [Polygon smooth] is not a recommended method for anti-aliasing. Use
>   Multisampling instead.

Comment: Ye gods, the dreaded polygon smoothing! I already forgot that this ancient abomination still lurks in R'lyeh. Nice catch and good luck with further haskelly journeys! (Go ahead and make the switch to buffer objects sometime.)

Comment: @Kos, I'm still learning OpenGL, don't know anything about "buffer objects". Thanks for giving a tip for improvement, I'll start searching and learning about it now. :)